# Express: Internal Server Error causes server to stop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

My problem is that the Express-Server shuts down, if I get a server error. For example if express can not connect to the Database I get an error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 (..)
```

Then the server is not running any more. I tried to handle my server errors with [this guide](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) as you can see in my code snippet. I want the server to continue even when there is thrown an error.

```
 const express = require('express');
 const methodOverride = require('method-override');
 const app = express();
 const mysql = require('mysql');
 const connection = mysql.createConnection({
     host     : 'localhost',
     user     : 'XXX',
     password : 'XXX'
 });
 app.use(methodOverride());
 app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
     res.status(500);
     // res.render('error', { error: err });
     res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
 });


 /*Webservices: */
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.send('Hello World!');
 });

 app.get('/database', function (req, res) {
         connection.query('SELECT 2 AS solution', function (err, rows, fields) {
             if (err) throw err;
             console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
             res.send(rows[0].solution.toString());
         });
 });


 /*Start Server: */
 app.listen(3000, function () {
     console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
 });
```

Comment: Uhhh, yeah.  You  have no useful error handling.  What do you expect `throw err` to do with no useful way to catch that exception.  Put real error handling in your code for every single place you can get an error.  Now, if you can't get a connection to your database, you're probably just going to have to return 500 errors to all requests that need the database, but your server can stay up if you handle the connection error appropriately.

Comment: ok so i wrapped my `connection.query` function in a `try` and catched like this: `try{connection.query('SELECT 2 AS solution', function (err, rows, fields) {
             if (err) throw err;
             console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
             res.send(rows[0].solution.toString());
         });
     }catch(err){
         res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
     }` my server stops anyways. I guess im missing something

Comment: You can't use try/catch around an async callback.  Async callbacks happen sometime LATER.  You have to catch the exception INSIDE the callback itself.  But, in this case, you don't even need to throw it.  You need to just decide what to do when you get the error.  Probably something like `return res.status(500).send("database error")`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. You can post your answer if you want I will mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get an error from your `connection.query()`, you are throwing an exception that is not handled.  The key to keeping your server running is to appropriately handle ALL errors that can occur and make sure that something safe (for your server) happens if you get that error.

In this case, since this is inside an async callback, the only place you can safely handle that error is inside that callback itself.  You can't throw an exception and catch it at a higher level from within a plain async callback.

So, I'd suggest something like this:

```
app.get('/database', function (req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT 2 AS solution', function (err, rows, fields) {
         if (err) {
             res.status(501).send("database query error");
         } else {
             console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
             res.send(rows[0].solution.toString());
         }
    });
 });
```